# How to avoid reinstall of package that defined as url for archive or repo with Pip

Tags: python, pip

Lets say I have `requirements.txt` like this:

```
Django==1.6    
pytest==2.5.2
https://github.com/pelme/pytest_django/archive/76cb4583eb9d08fd3e42c493d73da7e134a5975d.zip
```

In this case - `pytest_django` will be reinstalled after each `pip install -r requirements.txt` call. And I want avoid that.

I can add `#egg=pytest-django` to the end of url in `requirements.txt` and `pip` will skip it if it find that package with name `pytest-django` already installed. BUT - with this workaround Pip will not recognize if I change my url-requirement to a different version - so this is even worse that if it will be reinstallled every time.

How to manage this case properly? How can I add version info to a requirement defined as url?